# Explain iOS build and compile?

Tags: ios, compiler-construction

I'm new to iOS dev (Java native) and I was kinda confused on how an app is compiled. I'm assuming it goes from the `main.m` file in the Supporting Files folder, which hands off command to the `AppDelegate`. Then depending on the state of the app (like `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, or `applicationWillResignActive`) it runs the commands in that method.
So if like my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` sets the `window.rootViewController` to another file - `WXController`, for example, it then passes control to `WXController` and runs all the methods in there in a sort of '`while-loop-esque`' way?

Is my understanding even close to how compiling and building actually is?

Comment: Your question is a bit of a mish-mash. You ask about the build-steps and you are describing program-flow. You might want to read in detail about the concept of "UIViewController", "UIView", "selector", "UIEvent", "NSNotification" and "delegation" to get a better idea of common classes and patterns.

Comment: @Till I don't think that will help him. His question is about the compiler and in order to understand this he has to go to a lower level, to the compiler level. The normal patterns like viewControllers, views, selectors, events and notifications are multiple levels above that.

Comment: @NilsZiehn you might be perfectly right. I guessed that he was actually interested in the details of the program flow. You guess that he is actually interested in the details of compiling and linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did assume wrong. But this is neither the case for Java!

If you are interested what happens when you build your project, you can click in Xcode on your project file (usually the top most in the file menu, unless you are using workspaces). These are the project settings. One of it's tabs is calles 'Build Phases'. Here you can see listed what the compiler will do and in which order!

But to give you a quick introduction on how things work in C and C similar programming languages: There are the source files and the header files. Usually all source files ( the ones that contain your actual code in case of objective-C these are the .m-files) are compiled in random order (ofc. there is an order, but it is not important since the source files should never reference each other! ). The header files (.h-files) are used to tell the compiler about all the variables and methods that are supposed to be contained in other source files. This information will be kept as references while compiling the sources and then later used for linking everything together. After everything is compiled (result are the object files *.o),the references generated from the header files linker flags are used to link all your objects together.

Comment: Header files do not play any role in the linker-phase.

Comment: Simple but closer to reality; header files are copied into the source files by the preprocessor before those sources are compiled.